# Custom view with already existing controls

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-custom-view, visual-editor

I'm trying to create a re-usable control that I can just add whereever I like with already existing controls so I need no attributes, need nothing to add.

I just want the control to show up my Visual Editor when I drag the "Custom View" to the Layout.

I have a simple **view_textseek.xml** as example Layout that I don't want to recreate everytime I want "Text and a Seekbar" in case I use it on 3 different places (for example: a colorpicker later). Or just a control with both a "TextView" and a "SeekBar"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_textseek_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/view_textseek_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_textseek_container_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_textseek_text"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/view_textseek_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:max="255"
            android:progress="0" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is basically my class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class TextSeekView extends RelativeLayout
{

    public TextSeekView(Context context) { super(context); init(context); }
    public TextSeekView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); init(context); }
    public TextSeekView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) { super(context, attrs, defStyle); init(context); }

    protected void init(Context context)
    {
        if (!isInEditMode())
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_textseek, this, true);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I just want to "collect" multiple already existing controls and have one "View" or "Control" to handle these. It does not show up in the editor.

Or is this due to the some old type of idiotic bug that you have to restart your environment for "custom" Views to be loaded correctly?

And I need no special attributes on my other views, nothing at all and I just want to be able to show this layout again and again when adding it, or any other layout.

Like C#, add 3 textboxes to a control just cause you use 3 textboxes each time. Then, drag that control out on the Form whenever you want 3 textboxes - nothing more to it!

Comment: Do you want to view your custom view on graphical editor or on palette? If you want to show only on graphical editor search for isInEditMode method else I've no idea.

Comment: I haven't found any information as to what to do when overriding the isInEditMode method, just seen it called in a constructor/init method but no mention of what to do to make you see how the "View/Control" looks like. I want to be able to see how the control looks like, say I have 2 textviews and I scale the control as I want it; more difficult when I have no clue where on the control they are, just a white blank space doesn't say very much.

Comment: I've only worked on custom views for "ListView" but they still look like "ListView" does and not what my control will look like when executing it, so very confusing how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code:

```
protected void init(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_textseek, this, true);

    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        // isInEditMode returns true when you show a view on graphical editor. Returns false while showing on running app.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried just having the "upper" part of the code with the LayoutInflater since I didn't found what  to put in the !isInEditMode() if clause, but this works for some reason that it didn't before...